# MongoDB MMS API 404

Tags: mongodb-mms

I'm trying to find the endpoint for MMS per MongoDB's [documentation on the MMS API](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/core/api/), but when I try a variety of endpoints, such as :

```
* https://myhost:8080/api/public/v1.0/
* http://myhost:8080/api/public/v1.0/
* http://myhost/api/public/v1.0/
* https://myhost:8080/api/
* http://myhost:8080/api/
* etc...
```

I only see:

```
Yikes! The resource you requested was not found.
```

This is really frustrating and MongoDB's documentation on the MMS API is pretty badly designed.

Anyone ever worked with it before?

Comment: If you're using the cloud-hosted version of MMS (which matches the API docs you are referring to), the [`root` resource path](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/reference/api/root/) will be  `https://mms.mongodb.com/api/public/v1.0` as listed in the documentation. Your `myhost` examples suggest you're actually using the OnPrem version of MMS which is only provided to subscription customers (in which case you should open a Commercial Support issue for assistance ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Funny that the documentation doesn't mention it, but did you try https://mms.mongodb.com/api/public/v1.0/ ?

The example sections of the API documentation gives you all the information you need, including the correct endpoint, see the sub-pages of https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/reference/api/

Comment: Actually, the MMS API documentation does reference the [`root` resource path](https://mms.mongodb.com/api/public/v1.0) ;-).

Comment: So the problem is that the documentation actually refers to the cloud hosted version of MMS. I was looking for a solution to the in-house version of MMS. As per @Stennie's reply, I will talk to my team and try to get a commercial support case open.

That being said, if anyone knows how to work with the in-house api (what properties or configs need to be enabled, what settings, etc), then please do share.